# Indirect formula to find MIN of matching range

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with two sheets, first sheet contains `Name` (`col:C`), and `Finish time` (`col:G`), second sheet I have a column also called `Name`  (`col:A`) , and a column called `Personal Best Time` (`col:G`).

Currently, in `Sheet2:Col:G`, i'm using a formula to search `Sheet1` for the lowest `Finish time` value relating to that particular row's `Name` column (as below):

> =ArrayFormula( min( if('Sheet1'!C:C = A2, 'Sheet1'!G:G) ) )

But for every row in `Sheet2`, this formula needs to be copied, with the only difference being the `A2` reference (which is referring to the `Name` column of the current row).

So my hope was to create an indirect formula, where the specific range is entered in the header column, and automatically applied to each row.
So this is what I have so far:

> =ArrayFormula( IF( ISBLANK(A:A), "", IF( ROW(G:G)=1, "Personal Best Time",   ArrayFormula( min( if( 'Sheet1'!C:C = A2, 'Sheet1'!G:G ) ) )  )))

But how do I make it so that `A2` changes depending on the row number?

I tried `A:A`, but if I'm right, that would be attempting to compare the whole `Name` column from `Sheet2`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to formulas, another user edited my post and pointed me in the direction of indirect. And I figured most [excel-formula] would be the same as Google Spreadsheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this formula work as you want:

`=ArrayFormula( IF( ISBLANK(A:A), "", IF( ROW(A:A)=1, "Personal Best Time", ArrayFormula(Vlookup(A:A,SORT({Sheet1!C:C,Sheet1!G:G},2,1),2,0)))))`

Comment: Thats exactly what I needed, perfect! Thank you

Comment: Is it possible to do the same kind of function with `AVERAGE` instead of `SORT`? @chris-hick

Comment: I think this should work (you will need to format the column as time) : =ArrayFormula( IF( ISBLANK(A:A), "", IF( ROW(A:A)=1, "Average Time", ArrayFormula(Vlookup(A:A,QUERY({Sheet1!C2:C,ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(Sheet1!G2:G))},"select Col1,avg(Col2) where Col1 <> '' group by Col1"),2,0)))))

Comment: Thats fantastic! Thanks again :D